# Explicitly instantiated operator not exported

Tags: c++, templates

I have a class in my DLL. In the header I have

```
vector2d.h

#ifdef BUILD_DLL
#define DLL_API  __declspec(dllexport)
#pragma message ( "Using Export defines for DLL API" )
#else
#define DLL_API  __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

template<typename T1>
class Vector2D {
public:

    template <typename T2>
    Vector2D<T1>& operator=(const Vector2D<T2>& p_Right);

    template <typename T2>
    operator Vector2D<T2> () const;
    
    T x;
    T y;
};
```

And in the implementation I have the explicit instantiations

```
vector2d.cpp

#include "vector2d.h"

template <typename T>
template <typename T2>
Vector2D<T>::operator Vector2D<T2> () const
{
    return Vector2D<T2>(static_cast<T2>(x), static_cast<T2>(y));
}

template <typename T>
template <typename T2>
Vector2D<T>& Vector2D<T>::operator=(const Vector2D<T2>& p_Right)
{
    //if (&p_Right != this)
    {
        x = static_cast<T>(p_Right.x);
        y = static_cast<T>(p_Right.y);
    }
    return *this;
}

template class BUILD_DLL Vector2D<long>;
template class BUILD_DLL Vector2D<double>;

template BUILD_DLL Vector2D<long>::operator Vector2D<double>() const;
template BUILD_DLL Vector2D<double>& Vector2D<double>::operator=(const Vector2D<long>&);
```

The point of the first operator is so that I can cast a long to a double but not the other way around because of loss of precision.
The point of the second operator is so that I can assign a long to a double but not the other way around because of loss of precision.

Within the DLL everything works fine. But when I use that class from another DLL only the assignment operator is exported but not the cast operator. When I am trying to use the cast I get a linker error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol. We are using VS2010 compiler.

Why does the assignment operator work but the cast doesn't?

Comment: Not enough data (code). Please provide full header file and respective cpp file clearly stating which is which. Where is implementation of template, where is declaration of import and export of template instantiation. Note some macro is needed to switch between export/import depending on context (which target is build).

Comment: Do you have an `extern template` declaration in the header? If not, how do you expect the compiler to know about the `Vector2D<long>` and `Vector2D<double>` instantiations?

Comment: No I don't but the compiler is not complaining. And the linker is also only complaining about the conversion operator when used from another DLL. The assignment operator and other functions which I didn't list above are exported correctly.